# Получение модификаций с помощью JSON API

Tags: moysklad-json-api

делаю запрос к API для получения модификаций товара https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/variant?filter=productid=bd72d8f9-55bc-11d9-848a-00112f43529a

В ответ приходит следующее:

```
    {
   "context":{
      "employee":{
         "meta":{
            "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/context/employee",
            "metadataHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/employee/metadata",
            "type":"employee",
            "mediaType":"application/json"
         }
      }
   },
   "meta":{
      "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/variant?filter=productid=bd72d8f9-55bc-11d9-848a-00112f43529a",
      "type":"variant",
      "mediaType":"application/json",
      "size":0,
      "limit":25,
      "offset":0
   },
   "rows":[

   ]
}
```

т.е пустой массив, тариф профессиональный, у данного товара точно есть две модификации

Comment: скорее всего, Вы не тот id товара вставляете. 
сделая запрос get .../entity/product/bd72d8f9-55bc-11d9-848a-00112f43529a
в полученном товаре какой у вас id.

Comment: ID товара беру из API, с поля id

Comment: Обратитесь в тех поддержку. Вашу проблему легче решить с ними

Comment: Я обращался, они сказали, что служба поддержки не предоставляет предоставляет консультаций по API и отправили сюда

Comment: пермиссии у пользователя все есть (на просмотр товаров, например)?

Comment: Да, товары получаю без проблем все (основная информация, картинки, остатки)